# Valid Attributes for Resources Created by CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

CloudFormation includes the `Fn::GetAtt` intrinsic function. How do I know what attributes are available for a given resource?

```
 ApiDefault:
  Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
  Properties:
   Name: "poc"
   Description: "Public interface for system-to-system order submissions."
   FailOnWarnings: true
 ApiDefaultDeployment:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
  DependsOn:
   - "ApiMethodImageSubmitPost"
  Properties:
   Description: "Production environment supporting version-1 of the interface."
   RestApiId: !Ref "ApiDefault"
   StageName: "v1"
 ...
 ApiUsagePlan:
  Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlan"
  Properties:
   ApiStages: 
   - ApiId: !Ref "ApiDefault"
     Stage: !GetAtt [ "ApiDefaultDeployment", "StageName" ]
```

In the above, "StageName" isn't a valid attribute. So, how do I find the valid attributes for the "AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ***Return Values*** section of any given resource [in the doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-deployment.html), usually around the end of the page just above the examples section.

First, the `!Ref` function is explained and then the `!GetAtt` properties if any are available (which is not the case with `AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment`).

In your particular case, you could pass the stage name as a parameter in the template, and `!Ref` it for both the `ApiDefaultDeployment` and the `ApiUsagePlan`.